# How to replace Google Now to TouchWiz?

Tags: launcher, google-now, samsung-touchwiz

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S4 on Android 5.1 Lollipop. I found Google Now in settings and I decided to check what is it. Now settings interface has changed and I don't know how can I replace Google Now back to TouchWiz.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 5.1, it could be: System Settings --> Default Applications --> Home. Select touchwiz and press the home key. Hope this helps.

Comment: Now settings are: <Search & Now> Accounts & privacy, Search language, Voice, Phone search, Now cards, About. <Home screen> App suggestions(boolean option).

Answer (score 1):

Uh, I'm not entirely sure what the question is so just tell me if I'm wrong.  If you pull up Google Now launcher under the apps section of settings there should be a button titled "clear defaults."  If you select this it should ask you which launcher you want to use next time you close an app.  You can also install a different launcher and the same thing will happen but the other way should be easier.

Comment: Settings has changed. I can't find apps section. Are there open source launchers?

Comment: It looks like you're pulling up the wrong settings app.  Try opening it through the quick settings bar.  I assume so, but I can't think of any off the top of my head.  I know Nova Launcher has a free version.  Sorry for the late answer, I just got a notification a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, open up Google Play, search for Google Now Launcher, select uninstall and it will revert back to Touchwiz interface